# How should lists of resources be handled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The dreaded "list of resources" questions have come up during the recent scope discussions. One answer to the question is that they shouldn't be handled at all, but I strongly believe that there is a lot to be gained by allowing at least a limited amount of this.

The origin of all greatness, Stack Overflow, has e.g. this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, which is very useful for a C++ programmer. A list for different instruments, going from beginner to expert, would be similarly useful for people playing those instruments. I have purchased books from scattered recommendations on this site, so the knowledge is there.

First thing is to decide if it should be allowed, and then if we want to go forward, in what forms it should be allowed.

(I know there are questions around this topic on the Meta already, but I didn't find one that matched this one completely.)

Answer (score 5):

I think these type of questions/lists should be limited, and kept outside the normal reputation generating system. If it is to be done as community wiki or on the Meta I don't know. One downside of having them as Meta is that most people don't visit the Meta, and a lot of first time visitors are interested in this. Maybe people with experience of the different systems can chime in.

Suggestions for these lists should be brought up in the Meta, to see if there is enough interest.

Comment: Totally agree, as I said in my answer [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/741/7356)

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: I thought this deserved its own topic, partly due to that answer of yours :).

Comment: I was thinking about creating a new topic as well, but I totally forgot it :P

Comment: Meta is not for site content, just meta content.  CW is the only option IMO, otherwise you can get endless unsupportable answers.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Someone mentioned that it was done through Meta at other Q&A sites, I think English Usage was the example. I think it's better to keep Meta for meta too.

Comment: @MatthewRead, So can we allow some community wiki posts for list of resources?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic That's not my decision to make, it has to be the community.

Comment: @MatthewRead So we put a vote?

Comment: Yes, [english.se] has a [`resources`](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag on their Meta site for this kind of thing. The [most commonly requested resource](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online) is also tagged [`faq`](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) there. I think the principle is that such resources are off-topic for the main site (as they are here), but they help people answer questions, so they belong on Meta.

Comment: I also posted my comment as an answer so that people can vote for it as a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

There’s precedent for this kind of thing on the network. For example, [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) has a [`resources` tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) on their Meta site for this kind of thing. Their [most commonly requested resource](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online) is also tagged [`faq`](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) there. I think the principle is that such resources are off-topic for the main site (as they are here), but they help people answer questions, so they belong on Meta.